# Android 5: button underneath softnavigation bar (Showcaseview legacy)

Tags: android, button, material-design

I am using the [legacy ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/tree/legacy) for Android. I notice that the Android 5 emulator puts the OK button underneath the softnavigation bar, whereas Android <= KITKAT did not have this behaviour.

See the OK button in the lower right corner here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWE3c.jpg

I already tried *android:fitsSystemWindows="true"* but no success. Here is the relevant code in the ShowcaseView.java that I found:

```
    mEndButton = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.showcase_button, null);
```

(Warning: Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element))
[..]

```
    if (!mOptions.noButton && mEndButton.getParent() == null) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lps = (LayoutParams) generateDefaultLayoutParams();
        lps.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        if (getConfigOptions().showcaseId==3) 
            lps.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        else
            lps.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        int margin = ((Number) (metricScale * 12)).intValue();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) // TODO: LOLLIPOP workaround
            lps.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin*5);
        else
            lps.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, margin);
        lps.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        lps.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        mEndButton.setLayoutParams(lps);
        mEndButton.setText(buttonText != null ? buttonText : getResources().getString(R.string.positive));
        if (!hasCustomClickListener) mEndButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        addView(mEndButton);
```

I don't know how to change this or how Android 5 / material design has caused this behaviour. I would be happy for a hint! :)

Answer (score 3):

For me works set manually the margin bottom without use the margin returned from the method to obtain int margin.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

int margin = ((Number) (context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 12)).intValue();

layoutParams.setMargins(margin, margin, margin, 120);
```

Hope it works...

---

The problem has been fixed [here](https://github.com/sergiiz/ShowcaseView/commit/692b59f794b84e215c03ef5158e30bce555ed240)...

Answer (score 3):

I found very easy fix for this in [one of pull requests](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView/pull/272#issuecomment-72611919)

Add:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
```

to your style/theme in values-v21/styles.xml.

Works well for me, checked on a real device - Nexus 5.